# Inserting special character in Redmine wiki page

Tags: formatting, wiki, redmine

I'm using Redmine and I'm trying to insert the special character `|` inside a table in a Redmine wiki page. I don't want this character to be parsed as a column separator.

I've achieved this by doing a `<code>|</code>` around this character, but I don't want to use the `code` tag, since this character will gain code attributes, namely the courier new font.

**Is there a tag for displaying plain text and avoid the parsing from the Redmine wiki engine?**
I'm reading the redmine wiki formatting documentation but it is very poor and points me to textile formatting which doesn't seem to include this special case.

Answer (score 23):

I could not get the exclimation point to work, but [this](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/11866) works for me.

`<notextile>|</notextile>`

Comment: exactly, as defined in the redmine user guide [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormatting#Tables)

Comment: Sometimes the behavior of notextile is not exactly the same.
For instance, beginning a block with two spaces and then a notextile will not create a "box"

Answer (score 11):

The only way I found out to overcome this problem is to insert the HTML code for the character I want to isolate. For instance, instead of putting an underscore and make the wiki think I'm starting an italic word, I have to put the HTML code for it:

`&#95;`

Example:

this is a `&#95;`test - `_`text comment here`_`

Without the underscore code (`&#95;`) redmine wiki engine will think that italic starts at test and this is the wrong result:

this is a *test - text comment here*

So, putting the ASCII code for the underscore corrects this problem. Unfortunately, this parsing is not very clever (yet I hope).

Here is a link for an ASCII code table with many symbols and characters:

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm